# how to use background image in Quasar2

Tags: css, vuejs3

I put an image in the background-image with css in the q-header, which causes the screen to temporarily not load on initial loading. It seems to be a bit different from the image blinking issue and does anyone know how to fix it?

The gif file is a bit choppy as it resizes, but I think you get the idea of the problem.

The deployment method is using SSG.
I used this package

https://www.npmjs.com/package/quasar-app-extension-ssg?activeTab=readme

Below is a video and code of the situation.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkTQU.gif)

```
// Header.vue
<template>
  <q-header bordered class="text-center flex justify-center header">
    <q-toolbar class="flex justify-evenly navbar">
      <router-link to="/" class="text-white">
        <q-icon name="home" size="sm" />
      </router-link>
      <q-tabs v-model="tab">
        <router-link to="/articles" class="text-white noFontDeco">
          <q-tab name="articles" label="Articles" />
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/daily" class="text-white noFontDeco">
          <q-tab name="daily" label="Daily" />
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/resume" class="text-white noFontDeco">
          <q-tab name="resume" label="Resume" />
        </router-link>
        <q-icon name="light_mode" size="sm" class="q-ml-md" />
      </q-tabs>
    </q-toolbar>
    <q-toolbar class="q-mt-md main-title">
      <q-toolbar-title class="text-h2 text-grey-3">Blog</q-toolbar-title>
    </q-toolbar>
  </q-header>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts"></script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import 'src/css/layout/header.scss';
</style>
```

```
// header.scss
.header {
  background-image: url('src/assets/okayama.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

I tried putting the q-img tag inside the q-header to load the image, but I'm having the same problem.